# Trouble with PolyLog function evaluation

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

New poster here, please forgive any formatting issues.

As part of a physics simulation I'm using an analytical expression for the definite integral

$$ f(a,b) = \int\limits_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{x^2}{e^{ax + b}-1}dx $$

in Mathematica. (It's related to the number density of particles in a Bose-Einstein distribution).

For simplicity let's consider the integral from x = 0 to 1. Also a and c are strictly positive. Then Mathematica gives this function containing PolyLogs

```
(a^2 (-a + 3 I \[Pi] + 3 Log[-1 + E^(a + b)]) +  6 a PolyLog[2, E^(a + b)] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^b] -  6 PolyLog[3, E^(a + b)])/(3 a^3)
```

which using some identities can be written in manifestly real form as

```
-((a^2 (a + b - Log[-1 + E^(a + b)]) + 2 a PolyLog[2, E^(-a - b)] +  2 PolyLog[3, E^(-a - b)] - 2 PolyLog[3, E^-b])/a^3)
```

Now for most values of a and b it works fine, but 3DPlotting the expression as a function of a and b reveals some problems. In particular, when a is small things get pathological.

[image: trouble]

For probably related reasons, Integrate and NIntegrate give different results for the integral over f(a,b) for e.g. a = 0.00002, b = 2. The analytical expression gives a third result that is even negative for some choices of parameters.

Plotting the integrand reveals a perfectly innocuous looking strictly positive function, btw.

Is there any way I can get the analytical expression to numerically evaluate to correct results for small a?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `WorkingPrecision->30` in your plot.

Comment: I'm really not fond of expressing the Bose-Einstein and Fermi-Dirac functions as compositions of the polylogarithm and $\exp$; so much room for numerical mischief.

Comment: `f[a0_?NumericQ, b0_?NumericQ] := With[{a = SetPrecision[a0, Infinity], b = SetPrecision[b0, Infinity]}, N[(a^2 (-a + 3 I \[Pi] + 3 Log[-1 + E^(a + b)]) +  6 a PolyLog[2, E^(a + b)] + 6 PolyLog[3, E^b] - 6 PolyLog[3, E^(a + b)])/(3 a^3), 3.1]];` <-- change the `3.1` to your desired precision.

Comment: Thank you Michael! That works perfectly. I was trying to change the precision before but evidently I need to invest some more time in learning exactly how that works :)

Answer (score 2):

Following up [J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140879/trouble-with-polylog-function-evaluation#comment380648_140879), here's a numeric way to compute somewhat quickly the OP's function via Gaussian quadrature.  Some effort has to be put in to determine the number of Gauss-Legendre points to achieve a certain precision.  (This could be done somewhat more slowly with `NIntegrate` of course.  `NIntegrate` is about the same speed as using the adaptive precision approach in [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140879/trouble-with-polylog-function-evaluation#comment380600_140879), which was used to measure the error below. The approach below is about 50 times faster than either `N[]` on exact input or `NIntegrate[]`.)

```
With[{grd41 = NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[41, MachinePrecision],
  grd21 = NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[21, MachinePrecision]},
 nf[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] :=
   With[{data = Piecewise[{{grd41, a + 0.05 > 5 b}}, grd21]},
    With[{x = data[[1]]},
     (x^2/(Exp[a x + b] - 1)).data[[2]]
     ]];
 ]
```

Basic plot:

```
Plot3D[nf[a, b], {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Relative error:

```
Plot3D[(nf[a, b] - #)/# &@ f[a, b] // RealExponent,
 {a, 0, 1.95}, {b, 0, 2},
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> {-17.6, -5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {a, b, HoldForm@Log10["Rel. err."]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is even faster to use 21 Gauss points throughout, but the error is somewhat greater near `b == 0`:

```
With[{data = NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[21, MachinePrecision]},
 With[{x = data[[1]], weights = data[[2]]},
  nf[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := (x^2/(Exp[a x + b] - 1)).data[[2]]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One could use a Gauss-Kronrod pair from ``NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[]`` and use one estimate as the answer and the other as a precision check, among other possibilities. It's also a happy coincidence that the OP's desired integration range is the same as the default interval used by the quadrature rules in *Mathematica*.